Query many-to-many relationship in Prisma with "some"
Related to this question
I want to query a many-to-many relation in prisma, like "select all posts where the category ID contains ['1', '2'] ".
This seems fairly simple but even after spending 2 hours reading the Prisma docs on relational queries, I can't figure it out.
model Category {
  id               String    @id @default(cuid())
  name             String
  post             Post[]
}

model Post {
  id               String    @id @default(cuid())
  body             String
  category         Category[]
}

const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: {
        category: {
            some: {
                id: ['1', '2'],
            },
        },
    },
});

I want to get all posts: [post related with categoryId 1] && [post related with categoryId 2]
